# Implement library method in client project

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

We have a library containing a couple of assemblies with different functionality. We use this library in any frontend project we develop for our clients. Say I want to perform a particular task/method within the library, but the implementation of that method must be in the frontend.

In short: Class X in library calls method A of class Y in library, but method A needs to be implemented outside library. How?

Comment: Look at dependency injection and application composition

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a delegate from your lib and let consumers set it to point to their own implementation.

Example:

```
public delegate void DoWorkDelegate(CustomWorkParameters p);

public DoWorkDelegate DoWorkCallback
{
  get
  {
    return _workCallback;
  }
  set 
  {
    _workCallback = value;
  }
}
```

Later in your lib, when you need to actually do the work:

```
private void DoWorkInternal() 
{
  //Some work here

  //Check if caller set the callback
  if(_workCallback != null) 
  {
     _workCallback(localWorkParameters);
  }  
  else 
  {
     //throw exception
  }
  //Some more work here
}
```

Consumers should have a method respecting the delegate's signature and just pass it to your lib in the initialization phase.

Answer (score 0):

Define ClassY as an Abstract class, requiring the consumer to provide an implementation for methods defined as Abstract. Logic defined on the ClassY base will be common to all derived classes, and methods defined on ClassY base as "abstract" will need to be implemented by each derived class. Note I hacked this together for example only, so I make no claim that the actual code represents best practices!

The Abstract base class:

```
public abstract class AbstractLibraryClassY
{
    private static int _multiplier = 0;


    public abstract int MethodA(int SomeParam);

    // A simple example Property defined and implemented on the Abstract base class:
    public int Multiplier
    {
        get { return _multiplier; }
        set { _multiplier = value; }
    }


    private void someclassYImplementationStuff()
    {
        // Other implementation code . . .
    }
}
```

Two possible implementations of ClassY:

```
public class ConcreteClassYImplementationOne : AbstractLibraryClassY
{
    public override int MethodA(int SomeParam)
    {
        return SomeParam * this.Multiplier;
    }
}


public class ConcreteClassYImplementationTwo : AbstractLibraryClassY
{
    public override int MethodA(int SomeParam)
    {
        return SomeParam * this.Multiplier + 5;
    }
}
```

Class X, Consumes instances of ClassY:

```
public class LibraryClassX
{
    public int methodCallsClassYMethodA(AbstractLibraryClassY ImplementedClassY)
    {
        ImplementedClassY.Multiplier = 2;
        return ImplementedClassY.MethodA(100);
    }
}
```

A simple demonstration which uses class X to consume each implementation of ClassY in sequence:

```
public class Consumer1
{
    public void ConsumeClassX()
    {
        // Some hokey, arbitrary inputs:
        int MyInput = 200;
        int MyMultiplier = 2;

        // Consume Library Class Y using ConcreteClassYImplementationOne:
        AbstractLibraryClassY InstanceOf = new ConcreteClassYImplementationOne();
        InstanceOf.Multiplier = MyMultiplier;

        // Will output 400, per implementation defined in ConcreteClassYImplementationOne:
        Console.WriteLine("Output = " + InstanceOf.MethodA(MyInput).ToString());

        // Consume Library Class Y using ConcreteClassYImplementationTwo:
        InstanceOf = new ConcreteClassYImplementationTwo();
        InstanceOf.Multiplier = MyMultiplier;

        // Will output 405, per implementation defined in ConcreteClassYImplementationTwo:
        Console.WriteLine("Output = " + InstanceOf.MethodA(MyInput).ToString());

    }
}
```

Hope that helps. Also look into the commentor's suggestion re: Dependency Injection. I am only now looking into that (and it may be what I just described - not sure, gotta research!